# How to get last first and last from table with same date (query)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to ask about query, I want to make last insert item system.

If some people insert new item, I will insert date and time to the `track` table
[image: http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt306/mchlhlm/query/track_zps9jqrwcbp.jpg]

and then, I want to get the first and last rows of the day per date:

[image: http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt306/mchlhlm/query/sdsa_zpsntsjvoyz.jpg]

What query to get like that data?

Comment: Please explain your request in more detail. Your second table shows the first 'insert' for employee ids 1 and 2, not the first and the last insert. What exactly are you looking for? Secondly, please experiement with the SQL `SELECT` command and post your code in case you don's succeed.

Comment: I mean to get EMployee ID = 1 in 5/23/2014 in 1 row (distinct ) for example, i will get
insert_data_time = 8:00:00 (first), 8:02:00, 8:04:00, 8:30:00(last)

Comment: you need to put the "$row=*" in a while loop

Comment: hello phpPluginMaster, i need query for this problem...
shawnt00 and mureinik already answer my question.. but thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `group by` clause should do the trick:

```
SELECT   employee_id, 
         `date`,
         MIN(insert_data_time) AS first_time, 
         MAX(insert_data_time) AS last_time
FROM     track
GROUP BY employee_id, `date`
```

Comment: thank you mureinik :) you solve my problem hehe
sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first column is harder in MySQL but I can give you the rest. Do you really need to number the output rows that way?

```
select
    Employee_ID, `date`,
    min(Insert_date_time) as First_Time, max(Insert_date_time) as Last_Time
from track
group by Employee_ID, `date`
```

Comment: thank you shawnt00 :) you solve my problem hehe
sorry for my bad english :)